# Ruby gems fighting for two separate versions of activesupport?

Tags: ruby, rvm

I'm trying to run the resque server from the command line using:

```
rake resque:work
```

and ruby is complaining as follows:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport":
  In Gemfile:
    daemon-kit (>= 0) ruby depends on
      activesupport (< 3.2.0, >= 2.3.5) ruby

    actionpack (>= 0) ruby depends on
      activesupport (3.2.12)
```

How do I resolve these dependencies? Can I install two versions of activesupport in the same RVM gemset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to downgrade your version of activesupport to a version that supports daemonkit - or look for an updated version of daemonkit.  Your current version of rails / activesupport is newer than the version supported by your version of daemon-kit.

You can have multiple versions of activesupport in a single gemset, but only one of them can be activated at once.